# Increment/decrement numbers and letters by 'n'

Tags: javascript

I have a function `encryptString(string, shift)`.

- If `encryptString('c', 1)`, then `c` becomes `d`.
- if the arguments are `encryptString('c', -1)`, then `c` becomes `b`.
- If `shift` is greater than 26, or less than 0, the letter/number wraps back around. Meaning in `encryptString('a', 29)`, `a` becomes `c.

I believe this could be solved using the `charCode()` functions, but I started using `reduce`, and would like to solve it with what I have.

My attempt below can shift letters and numbers, but only if they're within the array length. If `shift` is greater than 26, it doesn't work.

I'd appreciate any input I can get.

```
const encryptString = (str, shift) => {
  if(!str.match(/^[a-z0-9]+$/i)) { throw new Error }

    const caps = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'.split(''); 
    const letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split('');
    const numbers =  '123456789'.split('');

    const reduction = str.split('').reduce((a,b) => {
      caps.includes(b) ? b = caps[caps.indexOf(b) + shift] || caps[shift] : null;
      letters.includes(b) ? b = letters[letters.indexOf(b) + shift] || letters[shift] : null;
      numbers.includes(b) ? b = numbers[numbers.indexOf(b) + shift] || numbers[shift] : null;
      a.push(b);
      return a;
    }, [])

    return reduction.join('');
};
```

Some additional cases:

```
encryptString('JavaScript', 3) => 'MdydVfulsw' // passes
encryptString('mqblhw', -1) => 'lpakgv' // passes
encryptString('z956qau', 29) => 'c845tdx' //code above fails 
encryptString('password123', -266) => 'jummqilx567' // code above fails
```

Comment: Just FYI, this is called a Caesar Cipher or Shift Cipher which might help with searching for more information.

Comment: use modulus `%`

Comment: This might help: https://learnersbucket.com/examples/algorithms/caesar-cipher-in-javascript/

Comment: "**would like to solve it with what I have**" He's learning how to program.  I don't think he needs the solution spoon fed to him or copied from somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks for the comments everyone. I did experiment with modulus earlier, but I guess I wasn't implementing it correctly. I'll give it another go. Thank you